# How would I write separate words to a file, with words between them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, append

I am trying to write words from `words.txt` to `newfile.txt` using python3, with a format like this:

words.txt:

```
Hello
I
am
a
file
```

and I want the word `Morning` added between each new word in `words.txt`, inside a new file called `newfile.txt`.

so `newfile.txt` should look like this:

```
Hello
Morning
I
Morning
Am
Morning
A
Morning
File
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Sorry about the bad phrasing,
Gomenburu

Comment: for each `read` you will need two `write` operations - this is probably the easiest

Answer (score 0):

To avoid blowing main memory for a large file, you'd want to insert the extra strings as you go. It's not hard, just a little tricky to ensure they only go between existing lines, not at the beginning or end:

```
# Open both files
with open('words.txt') as inf, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(next(inf))        # Copy over first line without preceding "Morning"
    for line in inf:             # Lazily pull remaining lines from infile one by one
        outf.write("Morning\n")  # Write the in-between "Morning" before each new line
        outf.write(line)         # Write pre-existing line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as words_file, open("newfile.txt", "w") as new_words_file:
    new_words_file.write("\n".join([f"{word}\nMorning" for word in words_file.read().split("\n")]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    a = lines[i] + 'Morning' + '\n'
    with open('newfile.txt','a') as file:
        file.write(a)
        file.close()
```

This should do it!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this:

```
f1 = open( 'words.txt')
f2 = open( 'newfile.txt')
lines = f1.readlines()
for line in lines:
  f2.write( line + "Morning\n")
f2.close()
```